# Howto create Directory in Temp Install Dir for Custom Action

Tags: wix, installation, custom-action

I've got an C# Wix Custom Action which is reponsible for setting up Datatabase.
All needed Dlls are extracted during Installation into C:\windows\installer\currentinstalldir.

So thats fine. The needed Sql Files are in the same Directory, but they have to be copied to 
C:\windows\installer\currentinstalldir\sqlscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to get what i want.

This code used as PostBuild Function does what i need.

```
%wix%SDK\MakeSfxCA.exe “$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).CA$(TargetExt)” “%wix%SDK\x86\SfxCA.dll” “$(TargetPath)” “$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll”
```

Found on [buildmaestro](http://buildmaestro.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/c-dtf-using-locale-net-culture-folder-and-resources-files-for-translations-with-makesfxca-exe/)

But due to a limitation of cmd.exe [(max Chars)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) I could not add all files I need.

My Workarround ist to Install these Files as a hidden feature and pass the Directory via Install Property to my Custom Action.